# jQuery ajax request not to correct url

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send ajax request via jquery. Everything it's ok except url. It should be http://localhost:8080/register but is http://localhost:8080/login so it's a url of current page. Also when I'm debugging application I can see that this request goes to controller method with "/login" value. I don't know why. It's a code of ajax method:

```
$("#my-signin2").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/register',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            console.info(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And there are controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(){
    return Links.LOGIN.getUrl();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(){
    return Links.HOME.getUrl();
}
```

Also I'm using spring security and it's code of handling csrf token:

```
var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
var csrfToken  = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfHeader, csrfToken);
});
```

I'm getting correct answer from serwer, but from login method.

UPDATE:

Spring security was redirecting all unauthorized requests to login page, so request is ok. Thanks for help!

Comment: Add the necessary markup. Without it the answers will only be guesses.

Comment: Is there security around this app forcing all unauthorized requests to the login page, thus the call to register may be forcing a login for that reason?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was redirecting this link to login page. I forgot about security :) Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

You should prevent the default action first using `e.preventDefault()` then you could send the custom ajax request , like :

```
$("#my-signin2").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the page from refreshing

    ....
});
```

Comment: this the answer

Answer (score 2):

the `#my-signin2` must have an attribute `type="button"`
because when you dont set the `type`. by default it `submit`

Comment: Why you think it's a `<button>`?

Comment: It's a button, but it's not working after setting type.